# i want get return count rows when execute select into table_n from table

Tags: postgresql, select

when I run

```
select * into mobile_n from mobile where c_name='dic'
```

I want to get the reuslt of `select count(1) from mobile_n`

I tried

```
select count(1) 
from ( 
  select * into mobile_n from mobile where c_name='dic' 
  return * 
)
```

but it did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-selectinto.html.

> SELECT INTO creates a new table and fills it with data computed by a
> query. **The data is not returned to the client**, as it is with a normal
> SELECT. The new table's columns have the names and data types
> associated with the output columns of the SELECT.

emphasis/bold by me.

work around:

```
create table mobile_n as select  * from mobile limit  0;
with a as(
insert into  mobile_n select  * from mobile where c_name = 'dic' returning 1)
select count(*) from a;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `CTE` for `count` result

```
WITH result AS (
    select * 
    into mobile_n 
    from mobile 
    where c_name='dic' 
    RETURNING 1
)
SELECT count(*) 
FROM result;
```